Dialog navigation Flutter with AutoRoute
How can I use AutoRouter inside an AlertDialog in Flutter while ensuring that the route context (RouteData) is available and properly scoped, so that I can navigate between nested routes like AddDocumentPage and SubmitDocumentPage within the dialog? I got no code yet, but I want to push inside a dialog and then just the content inside it changes, allowing me to press back button and literally navigate inside it.
